# To setup a new server joining the existing production server group, risk?

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013

we have BizTalk 2013 Enterprise, currently have a single application server with databases hosted in a another SQL Server, have SSO running together with the application server, no cluster setups. We are running into capacity issues, therefore looking to add another server to join the existing group as 2nd processing servers. Trying to understand the risk it could incur, do we need to plan any outage window. What I would think is just to join and configure the host instances on the 2nd server it should pick up message box naturally, something else I should be aware of? Thanks!!

Comment: Have you looked at what the bottle neck is with the current BizTalk setup?  e.g. using the PAL analysis tool?   You might find that it is the DB that is the bottle neck, and adding another BizTalk server will make things worse instead of better if you have not done that analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your predictions are mostly correct.  Newly added BizTalk Host Computers will begin processing as soon as enabled.

Having the Master Secret Server on the other BizTalk server is not a specific problem, but moving the MSS to the SQL Server is generally considered a better solution.

However, for general risk mitigation, you should add the new server during a regular maintenance window or downtime.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Johns answer, you will need to set up a clustered host to use with certain adapters, such as POP3, FTP(s), SFTP & MSMQ to prevent the same message being picked up twice. You probably will want to create such a host and move adapters to that host before you add another BizTalk Server to the group.

See [Considerations for Running Adapter Handlers within a Clustered Host](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa561801.aspx)